# Object in Kotlin/Singleton -> different instance (?)

Tags: object, kotlin, singleton, fragment, toolbar

I have an app with a bottom navigation and a toolbar.
The bottom navigation opens different fragments and the toolbar is suppose to change depending on the fragment (not implemented yet).

The toolbar is initialized in the main activity and depending on which fragment will be opened the menu of the toolbar will be inflated differently. There are different methods in the main activity which inflate the menu and set up the onClickListeners.

Inside OnCreate in MainActivity

```
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_container, QuickNPangFragment.QuickNPangFragment.newInstance(), "activitySelection")
                .addToBackStack("navigation_quick")
                .commit()
            supportFragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
        }
[...]

        val toolbar: Toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbarNew)
        when (supportFragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(supportFragmentManager.backStackEntryCount-1).name) {
            "navigation_quick" -> setQuickMenu(toolbar)
            "navigation_location" -> setLocationMenu(toolbar)
            "navigation_friends" -> setFriendsMenu(toolbar)
        }

[...]

    private fun setQuickMenu(toolbar: Toolbar) {
        toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu_main)
        toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener {
            QuickNPangFragment.QuickNPangFragment.newInstance().setQuickMenuItemClickListener(it.itemId)
            true
        }
    }
```

Inside QuickNPangFragment

```
    object QuickNPangFragment {
        fun newInstance() = QuickNPangFragment()
    }
```

There is something wrong in my understanding of this concept of the singleton: I think that only ONE instance of this fragment will be created, so whenever I call the newInstance() method of the fragment, it will return the same instance.

When running the debugger though it shows that the reference to the QuickNPangFragment object that is added when calling onCreate (this = {QuickNPangFragment@10915}... << this is the address, correct?) is different from the one when setting up the onClickListener in the setQuickMenu method (this = {QuickNPangFragment@11154}).

1) What am making wrong? and/or Where is the misunderstanding of that concept?
2) Is it ok to change the toolbar menu depending on the fragment?

Comment: You have multiple pointers for the same Singleton Object. Try to make some changes, like setting a variable and check if you get the same change into the other one.

Comment: Based on the code snippets it seems there is a class named `QuickNPangFragment`, an object of the same name and you create instances of the class.